# When a variable type is given at declaration, is it redundant to use as operator

Tags: typescript

I have come across a code block like this
`shape:IPoint={x,y,z} as IPoint;` 
Is this the correct way of using as keyword?

Comment: You've got a question in your title whose answer could be the opposite of the one in your question text. Not sure which to answer... Yes it is redundant. Yes, it is "correct" in as much as it will compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`as` is a type assertion, if the object { x, y, z } conforms to the interface then it's redundant.

For example here it would be redundant:

```
interface IPoint { x: number, y: number, z: number }
let x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
let shape:IPoint={x,y,z} ; // no need to assert
```

If the object does not conform to the interface, but we want to force the assignment, then the assertion is not redundant (but the explicit variable type arguably is)

```
interface IPoint { x: number, y: number, z: number, w: number }
let x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
let shape = {x,y,z} as IPoint; // not really a point but we have some reason to pretent it is a IPoint
```